# How to access iOS private APIs in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-privateapi, quartz-core

How can I call non-public iOS functions and acces non public properies from Swift? Specifically, I would like to use one non-public class in QuartzCore framework.

One solution that came to my mind is to create "bridging" Objective-C project that would wrap this non-public APIs into public ones and than call this Objective-C functions from Swift. However, my solution is pure Swift now and I would prefer to keep it that way. Is there any more staitforward way? (for example adding something to [Objective-C bridging header file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html))

Note: *I know what you are thinking, private APIs are private because they should not be used. I know the risks, I am aware of all the donwsides, app store restrictions etc. After all that carefully considered and lot of research, it unfortunatelly still seems the best way to go in this particular case.*

Comment: If you add properly the declaration of the private methods to a bridging header file, as if they were in a category (named, say, `PrivateButImmaUseTheseAnyway`), does that work?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I am not sure that I understand what you mean. I did not know whether it is possible to declare just a method in bridging header file. I tryied to declare the whole private class - I got a compilation error saying the class does not exist but maybe I did not do it correctly.

Comment: I mean, you declare the private class along with a category, like this: `@interface NSPrivateClass (PrivateStuff)`, and add the declaration of private methods there.

Answer (score 22):

You can do the very same trick that you would do if your project was in
Objective-C.

Create a header file and put the declaration of a category on the class, along with the declaration of the private methods you wish to expose. Then, tell the Swift compiler to import this bridging header.

For demonstration purposes, I'm going to poke around in the internals of `NSBigMutableString`, a private subclass of `NSMutableString`, and I will call its `_isMarkedAsImmutable` method.

Note that here, the entire class itself is private, hence I have to declare it as a subclass of its real superclass first. Because of this, I could have as well declared the method right in the declaration of the class itself; that, however, wouldn't have demonstrated the usage of the `(Private)` trick-category.

If your class is public, then obviously you will only need the category, and you won't need to (re-)declare the class itself.

Bridge.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableString (Private)
- (BOOL)_isMarkedAsImmutable; // this is a lie
@end

@interface NSBigMutableString : NSMutableString
@end
```

s.swift:

```
let s = NSBigMutableString()
println(s._isMarkedAsImmutable())
```

Compile and run:

```
$ xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o foo -import-objc-header Bridge.h s.swift
$ ./foo
false
$
```

Comment: Works perfectly, in my case (MacOS SwiftUI app using NSWindow private API) I had only to add a `#import <SwiftUI/SwiftUI.h>`

Answer (score 8):

You can get private classes using `NSClassFromString:` and interact with them using [performSelector](https://github.com/tokorom/performSelector-swift).