# Invoking an objective-c private class's method in Swift using reflection

Tags: swift, reflection, selector

At first, I want to invoke a private class's instance method from a objective-c static framework.

If I use OC, I can invoke it like this:

```
Class TargetClass = NSClassFromString(@"TheNameOfTargetClass");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"sharedInstance");
IMP imp = [FLEXNetworkRecorderClass methodForSelector:selector];
id (*func)(id, SEL) = (__typeof__(func))imp;
id instance = func(TargetClass,selector);
if(instance){
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"targetFunction");
    IMP imp = [defaultRecorder methodForSelector:selector];
    id (*func)(id, SEL) = (__typeof__(func))imp;
    id result = func(instance,selector);
}
```

The **result** is what I want, but How to do it in Swift?

I have tried a lot, but I can I don't know how to translate some of above, like:

```
id (*func)(id, SEL) = (__typeof__(func))imp;
```

and if I want to invoke **methodForSelector** I need to convert to **NSObject** using:

```
as! NSObject
```

and then, it crash.

So how to that?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174541/how-to-access-ios-private-apis-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access iOS private APIs in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174541/how-to-access-ios-private-apis-in-swift)