# Declaring callback function inside FSEventStreamCreate

Tags: objective-c, macos, fsevents

There are a couple examples of using an FSEvent to listen for changes in the file system.

[How to listen for file system changes MAC - kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154845/how-to-listen-for-file-system-changes-mac-kfseventstreamcreateflagwatchroot)

and

[FSEvents weirdness on OS X Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913401/fsevents-weirdness-on-os-x-leopard/913636#913636)

When creating the event with `FSEventStreamCreate` they all seem to pass the callback item just fine. No parameters or anything, just `&feCallback`. Basically it seems as if they're passing a variable rather than a function, if that makes sense.

But I'm getting a `Use of Undeclared identifier` error when I try to do it. What gives?

```
 FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, 
                                                  &feCallback, // what does '&' mean? Why are no parameters passed?
                                                  &cntxt, 
                                                  pathsToWatch, 
                                                  kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, 
                                                  1,
                                                  kFSEventStreamCreateFlagWatchRoot );
```

and then later have the callback function:

```
static void feCallback(ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                       void* pClientCallBackInfo,
                       size_t numEvents,
                       void* pEventPaths,
                       const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                       const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[]) 
{
        NSLog(@"The file changed!"); 
}
```

I'd love some sample code to get the open-source helper object here working: https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/fs-notifier/overview

But same thing. It has the method:

`- (id) initWithCallback:(FSEventStreamCallback)newCallback path:(NSString *)newPath;`

and I can't pass it a `newCallback` because of the error described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When creating the event with `FSEventStreamCreate` they all seem to pass the callback item just fine. No parameters or anything, just `&feCallback`.
>
> ```
> FSEventStreamRef stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL, 
>                                                  &feCallback, // what does '&' mean? Why are no parameters passed?
> ```

The `&` is the “address of” operator, and evaluates to a pointer to its operand. It's not really necessary here; a function name not in a function call always evaluates to the pointer to the function, with or without `&`.

So this passes the pointer to the `feCallback` function, which is how the FSEventStream object will call it back.

> Basically it seems as if they're passing a variable rather than a function, if that makes sense.

That does make sense, but no, that's not correct. They are passing the function itself.

It is possible to declare a variable that holds a pointer to a function. If `feCallback` were such a variable, then `feCallback` and `&feCallback` would mean different things: `feCallback` would be the pointer to the function (inside the `feCallback` variable), whereas `&feCallback` would be the pointer to the variable.

In your case, though, with `feCallback` being a function, the two expressions are equivalent; either way passes the function pointer.

> But I'm getting a Use of Undeclared identifier error when I try to do it. What gives?

You haven't declared that identifier (in this case, that function).

> and then later have the callback function:

That's the problem. You have the callback function defined after your use of its name, but you did not declare the function *before* using its name. You must declare the function before you can use it (or pass it anywhere).

The reason is because the compiler doesn't know what “`feCallback`” is until you tell it, which is what the declaration does. When you try to refer to “`feCallback`” before declaring or defining it, the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about.

The other way would be to move the function's definition up. A definition counts as a declaration for everything that follows it. I'd leave the definition where it is, though, and just add a declaration near the top of the file.

Either way, then the compiler will know what `feCallback` is when you pass it to `FSEventStreamCreate`.

Comment: Huh. It never occurred to me that simply reordering the actual functions would make this work. I was thinking I needed to somehow "create an instance of" the function, which I was obviously having trouble with. If you have the `static void feCallback` bit written above the method in which you use `FSEventStreamCreate` everything works fine. Guess this is a place where coming from a Java/C# background (where all that is done automatically?) is a bit of a painful transition to Obj-C. :) Thanks for the help.